# Unblock people not in the list of blocked people

Tags: facebook

I wanted to know how to unblock someone who I blocked few years back.  The name is not showing in blocked people, and when I search for such a person, it says no results for this person although the person has a Facebook account.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a search privacy setting in Facebook. If it is turned off, you cannot search the person on Facebook even if he or she has an account.